# Where can I find information on shredding xml with .nodes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, xml

I recently saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248510/how-to-returns-the-text-of-an-xml-value-with-a-space-between-the-nodes-value/7258556#7258556) on SO which uses the "local-name" value while shredding xml using `.nodes()`. I've never seen this before:

```
select T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(128)') as Name,
       T.N.value('.', 'varchar(max)') as Value
from @xml.nodes('/data/*') as T(N);
```

Where can I find the definitive document on commands like `.nodes()` and `.value()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those [methods are part of the xml data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx) in Sql Server, starting from 2005, since the xml data type was implemented for Sql Server 2005.

The `local-name` method is part of [XQuery implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189254.aspx) of Sql Server. Its far from being a complete implementation of the [XQuery specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/), but it can be helpful.